# Cordova ios in app browser plugin back to the app loading url again in default browser

Tags: jquery, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, inappbrowser

I am using cordova in app browser plugin in my app.

In app browser plugin is installed properly.

The redirection of link in safari browser is working as expected with below code.

```
$(document).on('click', '.slide a[href^="http"]', function (e) {
      var linkUrl = $(this).attr('href');
      window.open(encodeURI(linkUrl), '_system', 'location=no,clearcache=yes,clearsessioncache=yes');
      e.preventDefault();
});
```

It's opening the link inside safari browser.

But the issue is when i go back to the app from top left corner back button. Instead of loading the app again it is loading the same URL in default browser. And user not be able to go back to the app and force fully need to close the app.

What am i missing or what i am doing wrong.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try to use InAppBrowser or childbrowser to open the links with in the app, it is should solve it.

Comment: @MVG1984 Yes i am already using InAppBrowser plugins. What changes do i need to make for that ? How can i use childbrowser ?

Comment: Look https://github.com/alunny/ChildBrowser , there is childBrowser.openExternal i think it is what you need.

Comment: @MVG1984 I am not sure but will child browser open the links in safari browser using new window ? and let user back to the app once done. will it be possible with that ?